How to Pass Variables between Nested Includes in Gulp File Include?
I'm using gulp-file-include to build my HTML files and I'm running into an issue with passing variables between nested include files.
File Structure:
.
├── index.html
└── template-parts
    └── common
        ├── header.html
        └── headerMenuList.html

Problem:
I want to pass a variable (nav) from index.html to header.html and then pass it from header.html to headerMenuList.html. However, I'm getting the following error:
[21:14:05] Starting 'htmlConcat'...
[21:14:05] 'htmlConcat' errored after 11 ms
[21:14:05] Error in plugin "gulp-file-include"
Message:
    JSON5: invalid character 'a' at 1:11
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false

index.html:
<!-- siteHeader -->
@@include('template-parts/common/header.html', { "nav": "about" })

header.html:
<!-- I want to pass the nav variable to this file -->
<p>Navigation: @@nav</p>
<!-- Passing nav to headerMenuList.html -->
@@include('./headerMenuList.html', { "nav": nav })

headerMenuList.html:
<!-- Trying to access nav variable here -->
<p>Current Navigation: @@nav</p>

What I've Tried:

Direct Variable Passing: Using @@include('./headerMenuList.html', { "nav": nav }) but it throws the JSON5 error.

String Interpolation: Tried using <%= nav %> inside header.html but it outputs <%= nav %> as a string instead of the value.

Using @@nav Directly: I tried using @@nav directly in header.html to pass the variable, but I get the same error. For example: @@include('./headerMenuList.html', { "nav": @@nav })

Direct String Testing: When I change it to @@include('./headerMenuList.html', { "nav": "about" }), it works, indicating that the variable isn't being passed correctly.


Question:
Is it possible to pass variables between nested include files in gulp-file-include? If so, what is the correct way to do this? If not, is there a workaround or alternative approach I can use to achieve this?

The issue you're encountering with gulp-file-include is how it handles variables and scope within nested files. Unfortunately, gulp-file-include doesn't natively support passing variables between multiple nested includes like you are trying to do.
Workaround:
While gulp-file-include doesn't automatically propagate variables through nested includes, there is a workaround where you can manually pass the variable at each step. Here’s how you can adjust your code:

Pass the variable from index.html to header.html directly.
Then, manually pass the same variable from header.html to
headerMenuList.html.

This way, you'll explicitly pass the nav variable at each inclusion point.
For example:
index.html


<!-- Pass "nav" from index.html -->
@@include('template-parts/common/header.html', { "nav": "about" })



header.html


<!-- Display the "nav" variable in header.html -->
<p>Navigation: @@nav</p>

<!-- Pass the same "nav" variable to headerMenuList.html explicitly -->
@@include('./headerMenuList.html', { "nav": @@nav })



headerMenuList.html:\


<!-- Access the "nav" variable in headerMenuList.html -->
<p>Current Navigation: @@nav</p>




hi  srdarkseer! thanks for your input.  ,you can see in my question that It's something i've already tried  it gave me this error (also attached in original question):
[21:14:05] Starting 'htmlConcat'...
[21:14:05] 'htmlConcat' errored after 11 ms
[21:14:05] Error in plugin "gulp-file-include"
Message:
JSON5: invalid character 'a' at 1:11
